# How to debug maven dependencies logic?

Tags: maven

Maven download package XYZ on compile time on step "maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)"

but `mvn -U -X -e dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep XYZ` doesn't show anything.

How can i find out why is maven downloading dependency XYZ?

---

edit:

don't want to turn this into a collective POM debug exercise, but here is what i am trying to debug:

after `mvn package` (with an empty ~/.m2/repository) i end up with

```
.m2/repository/log4j/log4j
├── 1.2.12
│   ├── log4j-1.2.12.jar
│   ├── log4j-1.2.12.jar.sha1
│   ├── log4j-1.2.12.pom
│   ├── log4j-1.2.12.pom.sha1
│   └── _remote.repositories
└── 1.2.17
    ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
    ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar.sha1
    ├── log4j-1.2.17.pom
    ├── log4j-1.2.17.pom.sha1
    └── _remote.repositories
```

i do not have any direct or indirect use of log4j. I'm pretty sure as soon as I post my pom someone will answer "of course you have ABC which everyone knows brings in XYZ"... but i would very much to understand how to force maven to show more information that helps me to get to that conclusion in different cases.

Comment: The first thing is: `maven-dependency-plugin:tree` shows only dependencies for the project in the pom but not the dependencies of plugins. Furthermore I see that you are using a quite old version of maven-compiler-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) Why do you need to know of that dependency which is I suppose not a part of your pom file?

Comment: spring is pulling in dozen of loggers, including lof4j. just want to add the exclude tags in the right place.

Comment: But regardless of the specific case, getting the true dependency tree would be nice for several reasons.

Comment: If you have a spring project and dependencies this output shows exactly the dependencies which are downloaded... Furthermore you don't need to set `-U` nor `-X` and not `-e` ... only `mvn dependency:tree`... I'm not sure what you are missing? Also many IDE's support this within from the IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ)?
Do you use a spring/spring boot parent for your project? Also please show the pom file..?

Comment: @khmarbaise edited question with more info than i could fit here. thank you!

Comment: What does your `dependency:tree` exactly show? Also list all maven plugins you are using...

Comment: I think you are correct about plugins... it might be used by the plugins not code/dependencies. is there a way to differentiate downloads for codebase vs plugins?

Comment: dependency:tree shows nothing with log4j.

Answer (score 2):

So some plugin you are using in your POM brings a log4j dependency.

First of all, this not really anything to worry about because these dependencies are not just for your JAR/WAR/EAR, but only during the build.

Secondly, excluding them at the plugin level will likely cause the build to fail.

Lastly, your problem might just be solved by updating your plugins to the latest version.

Comment: anyway to have maven show the reason it started to download something?

Comment: if you set `-X` you can see the plugin dependencies in the logs.